# Instantiating domain object and factory object with spring container

Tags: java, spring, aop

our application is using Spring container and Spring AOP.We need to Instantiate all the object from Spring Container,so that Spring AOP work with whole application
Is there any way where we can Instantiate  domain object,factory method from spring container.we dont want to use AspectJ

```
<bean id="ExBean" factory-bean="ExFactoryBean" factory-method="getObj">
<constructor-arg ref="runtimeBean"/>
<constructor-arg value="Add"/>
</bean>
```

I want to select interface implementing class at runtime and that class should be instantiated from Spring. we have use factory method for creating the class,but  classes bean instantiation at runtime  is not happening yet

Comment: I think this might help : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can configure spring to instantiate object from factory method

```
<bean id="exampleBean"
      class="examples.ExampleBean2"
      factory-method="createInstance"/>
```

- [3.2.3.2.2. Instantiation using a static factory method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/beans.html)

Comment: Thanks @Jigar and @Bozho.Yy problem is factory method has two  arguments and those arguments are instantiated at runtime,but Spring will instantiate Factory bean at compile time.what is the way to go forward??

Comment: `Spring will instantiate Factory bean at compile time` No it will initialize them at context initialization time if eager , invocation time if lazy. Spring beans are more of Service beans so it seems strange design to me.

Comment: sorry initialization is occuring at context initialization only.i was thinking wrong.but factory method require data from the request which will be available only at run time.so context initialization is not able to solve problem

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to make objects managed by spring:

- let spring instantiate them
- use apsectj weaving

No other way.